# Post Form DATA to another page after PHP Validation

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this issue with my validation and posting the data to another page.

Here is my form:

## Signup.php

```
<form id="regForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["submit.php"]);?>" method="post" name="regForm">
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label><input name="fname" type="text" size="25" maxlength="35" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fname'])){echo $_POST['fname'];}?>"/><br/>
    <label for="mdname">Middle initial:</label><input name="mdname" type="text" size="10" maxlength="35" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['mdname'])){echo $_POST['mdname'];}?>"/><br/>
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><input name="lname" type="text" size="25" maxlength="35" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lname'])){echo $_POST['lname'];}?>"/><br/>
    <br/>
    <label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" name="Signup" class="formButton" value="Signup" /></form>
```

And here is my submit.php which will validate the signup.html input

## submit.php

```
function msg($status,$txt)
{
    return '{"status":'.$status.',"txt":"'.$txt.'"}';
}

// we check if everything is filled in and perform checks
//check if fname is empty
if(!$_POST['fname'])
{
    die(msg(0,"<p>Please enter your first name.</p>"));
}
//check if lname is empty
if(!$_POST['lname'])
{
    die(msg(0,"<p>Please enter your last name.</p>"));
}
```

Now, my issue is this, in my "submit.php" file, I want to know what codes to put after the form fields validation that would enable me post the input data to another page because, I plan making it a two-page signup form. Let's say my next page is signup-2.html

how do I post the data after validation to the next page? I know how to retrieve the posted data on the next page like using Session or Echo the $_POST data but, my main issue is....how do I make the form post the data after the validation messages in my `submit.php` file?

Comment: put them in hidden variables in `signup2.php` form

Comment: change file name from `Signup.html` to `Signup.php`

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. However, I have a good idea about to populate the posted data in the next page but, my main problem lie on my submit.php file.

Comment: What do I put after the following codes in my submit.php file "if(!$_POST['lname'])
{
    die(msg(0,"<p>Please enter your last name.</p>"));
} "

Comment: There is no point putting anything after a `die()` command as that KILLS the script.

Comment: Thanks, Riggs. If am not to put die and the error message, what should I put then? Can you help me format this if(!$_POST['lname'])
{
    die(msg(0,"<p>Please enter your last name.</p>"));
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use header :

```
header("Location: your page url?fname=$_POST['fname']&lname=$_POST['lname']");
```

but before this do not echo or print anything otherwise it won't redirect to that page.

you can use the data on destination page like this:

```
$_GET['fname']
```

example:

**submit.php**

```
function msg($status,$txt)
{
    return '{"status":'.$status.',"txt":"'.$txt.'"}';
}

// we check if everything is filled in and perform checks
//check if fname is empty
if(!$_POST['fname'])
{
    die(msg(0,"<p>Please enter your first name.</p>"));
}
//check if lname is empty
if(!$_POST['lname'])
{
    die(msg(0,"<p>Please enter your last name.</p>"));
}

header('Location:download.php?fname='.$_POST['fname']."&lname=".$_POST['lname']);
```

**view.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<input type='text' id="fname" name="fname"/>
<input type='text' id="lname" name="lname"/>
<input type="submit" id="button" value="submit"/>
</form>

</body>


</html>
```

**download.php**

```
<?php
echo "First Name........".$_GET['fname'];
```

put these three file in same directory and run view.php. you will be ok.

Comment: This will change your $_POST parameters to $_GET.

Comment: Please, review my "submit.php" code and tell me exactly where to put the header location to make it post the data to the next page after the validation.

Comment: you want to get this if every thing is filled so put this after second if and see.one thing always check values using isset() method.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Suchit. But, I don't really understand what you are trying to explain. Could be a little more elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: function msg($status,$txt)
{
    return '{"status":'.$status.',"txt":"'.$txt.'"}';
}

// we check if everything is filled in and perform checks
//check if fname is empty
if(!$_POST['fname'])
{
    die(msg(0,"<p>Please enter your first name.</p>"));
}
//check if lname is empty
if(!$_POST['lname'])
{
    die(msg(0,"<p>Please enter your last name.</p>"));
}   header("Location: your page url?fname=$_POST['fname']&lname=$_POST['lname']"); then on your redirected page access the variables using $_GET method.

Comment: copy the above comment and replace with your submit.php and in header add your url to next page then echo $_GET['fname'];

Comment: It didn't work out. I even added exit(); after the header and location line.

Comment: Yea..it worked! Now, all I need to do is find a way to display my error properly on the first page with the "msg" error response.